tkinter menu add_command not working as intended
I am writing this program to show data in the form of tables using label and grids and have added a menu on each heading to perform operations on them
but the function I am trying to add to them is not running
the program showcasing the issue is given below:
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
data=[(1,'data 1'),(2,'data 2'),(3,'data 3')]
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

def menu_popup(event,m):
    reset(m)
    m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    m.bind('<FocusOut>',reset(m))
def reset(m):
    m.delete(0,END)
    #trying with lambda method
    m.add_command(label='task 1',command=lambda _:func2())
    #trying partial from functools
    m.add_command(label='task 2',command=partial(func1))

def func1():
    print('function 1')
def func2():
    print('function 2')

nr=1
Label(frame1,text='Sno',relief='solid').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(frame1,text='Heading',relief='solid').grid(row=0,column=1)
for i in data:
    n1=Label(frame1,text=i[0],relief='solid')
    n1.grid(padx=1,pady=1,row=nr,column=0,sticky='news')
    n2=Label(frame1,text=i[1],relief='solid')
    n2.grid(padx=1,pady=1,row=nr,column=1,sticky='news')
    rem_mb=Menu(n2,tearoff=0)
    n2.bind('<Button-3>',lambda e,m=rem_mb:menu_popup(e,m))
    nr+=1
root.mainloop()

as you can see, I tried using the lambda method and have even tried partial from functools
Am I doing something wrong with this code?

When you define a command, you have two main options. The first is to define a function elsewhere in code, which you did. In that case, you should reference just the name of this function (without parenthesis afterward) like this:
m.add_command(label='task 1', command=func1)

The other option is to use a lambda function, which defines the function right there without needing to define and name it elsewhere in code, like this:
m.add_command(label='task 1', command=lambda: print('function 1'))

Here is the complete code with the both options that I've mentioned, which both will print text to your console successfully.
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
data=[(1,'data 1'),(2,'data 2'),(3,'data 3')]
frame1=Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

def menu_popup(event,m):
    reset(m)
    m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    m.bind('<FocusOut>',reset(m))
def reset(m):
    m.delete(0,END)
    #lambda function
    m.add_command(label='task 1',command=lambda: print('function 1'))
    #defined function
    m.add_command(label='task 2',command=func2)

def func2():
    print('function 2')

nr=1
Label(frame1,text='Sno',relief='solid').grid(row=0,column=0)
Label(frame1,text='Heading',relief='solid').grid(row=0,column=1)
for i in data:
    n1=Label(frame1,text=i[0],relief='solid')
    n1.grid(padx=1,pady=1,row=nr,column=0,sticky='news')
    n2=Label(frame1,text=i[1],relief='solid')
    n2.grid(padx=1,pady=1,row=nr,column=1,sticky='news')
    rem_mb=Menu(n2,tearoff=0)
    n2.bind('<Button-3>',lambda e,m=rem_mb:menu_popup(e,m))
    nr+=1
root.mainloop()


Although your code fixes the lambda issue on m.add_command(...), but it does not address OP issue that the functions are not triggered when menu item is selected.  The issue is caused by the line m.bind('<FocusOut>', reset(m)).

You have a function call in m.bind('<FocusOut>', reset(m)). Remove it.
